# React js dynamic z-index when click on a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, functional-programming

What i want to accomplish is when i click on a box, the previous box to be behind the one that is on top, for better reference please check the next code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-payne-4644yf?file=/src/styles.css

Desired behavior:

1. click on red box
2. click on blue box

and the sequence from bottom to top would be: green,red,blue

I tried a lot of ways but im keep messing up the code, so any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const Test = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, label: "box 1", class: "box1", z: 0 },
    { id: 2, label: "box 2", class: "box2", z: 1 },
    { id: 3, label: "box 3", class: "box3", z: 2 }
  ]);
  
  const handleClickBox = id => {
    setData(p => {
      let tmpArr = [...p];
      tmpArr = tmpArr.sort((a) => a.id - (id + 1)).reverse().map((ta, i) => ({ ...ta, z: i })).sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      return tmpArr;
    })
  }

  return <div className="box-wrapper">
        {data.map((d, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={d.class}
              key={d.id}
              style={{ left: i * 100, zIndex: d.z }}
              onClick={() => handleClickBox(d.id)}
            >
              {d.label}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Test />
);
```

```css
.box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}

.box1 {
  background: green;
}
.box2 {
  background: red;
}
.box3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this not was my point, the two comments from below worked, so thank again for your dedicated time.

Answer (score 1):

When I was typing my response Layhout answered. That solution works, but mine is slightly different, you need to know the greatest value of zIndex.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, label: "box 1", class: "box1", index: 0 }, // red
    { id: 2, label: "box 2", class: "box2", index: 1 }, // blue
    { id: 3, label: "box 3", class: "box3", index: 2 } // green
  ]);

  const handlePosition = (index, selectedIndex) =>
    index === selectedIndex ? 2 : index > selectedIndex ? index - 1 : index;

  const handleClick = (selectedIndex) => {
    // nothing happens if we click on the first item
    if (selectedIndex === 2) return;

    setData(
      data.map((i) => ({
        ...i,
        index: handlePosition(i.index, selectedIndex)
      }))
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box-wrapper">
        {data.map((b) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={b.class}
              key={b.id}
              style={{ zIndex: b.index }}
              onClick={() => handleClick(b.index)}
            >
              {b.label}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the full implementation on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-glitter-6k7jl2?file=/src/App.js).

The most important fact is zIndex of each object is also a UI state, so it needs to be in useState to change with user clicks. After this, you need to implement an algorithm to reorder items based on the clicked item. That is this function:

```js
const handlePosition = (index, selectedIndex) =>
    index === selectedIndex ? 2 : index > selectedIndex ? index - 1 : index;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i will use or this approach or the one from John Li, the answer from the bottom. Great explanation also

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the desired result may actually be a solution that handles `z-index` independently, without adding to the given `data`, and is capable of handling more than 3 `div` items if needed.

Here is a basic example that uses a state array `activeList` to handle the changes of `z-index`, so it is independent to `data` and can still work if `data` scales.

It uses the `index` of the state array to calculate `z-index` for each item. On click event, it pushes an item to the end of array (so it will have the highest z-index), as a lightweight approach to handle the re-order of `z-index`.

Forked live demo on: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/switch-z-index-oo7i8d?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [activeList, setActiveList] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (id) =>
    setActiveList((prev) => {
      const current = prev.filter((item) => item !== id);
      return [...current, id];
    });

  const data = [
    { id: 1, label: "box 1", class: "box1" },
    { id: 2, label: "box 2", class: "box2" },
    { id: 3, label: "box 3", class: "box3" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box-wrapper">
        {data.map((b) => {
          const activeIndex = activeList.findIndex((id) => id === b.id);
          const zIndex = activeIndex >= 0 ? activeIndex + 1 : 0;
          return (
            <div
              className={b.class}
              key={b.id}
              style={{ zIndex }}
              onClick={() => handleClick(b.id)}
            >
              {b.label}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for your time and i got the point now.